# ImportError: cannot import name 'AdamOptimizer' in gpflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow

I want to use AdamOptimizer with GPFlow, however I cannot import it as suggested as the source code in this [link](https://github.com/ICL-SML/Doubly-Stochastic-DGP/blob/master/demos/run_regression.py) (line 26) specifies. I am unsure what I am missing. I have tried with different gpflow versions (1.1.1 and 1.3).

Thanks

Comment: Do lines 24 and 25 come in just curious. Make sure to use pip or pip3 depending on your python

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using? Perhaps try 1.15? I just used Tensorflow 1.15 on the from gpflow.training import AdamOptimizer
and it worked to install a specfic version of TensorFlow use pip3 install tensorflow==1.5 I saw in the TensorFlow docs that AdamOptimizer came in the 1.14r or something so 1.15 version of TF might be the trick cause I just tested it

Comment: I tried using tensorflow version 1.5 and it works now. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it happens because you are using TF >=1.14. The released GPflow packages <= 1.4.1 support TF <=1.13.1 only. The GPflow `develop` branch now does support TF 1.14, but this has not yet been released.

There is an unofficial (in progress) [GPflow2](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/tree/awav/gpflow-2.0) with TF 2.0 support, if you are interested.

Comment: Using tf 1.12 and 1.5 worked for me in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This issue is now fixed in GPflow develop. See https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/pull/997.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the fixes from this pull request ([link](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/pull/997/commits/a57640978fb871a957264026f9c5322401be3b13)) into your `GPflow-1.4.1/gpflow/training/tensorflow_optimizer.py` file and reinstall GPFlow.